# how to check weather plain text is empty?

Tags: android, oop, kotlin

How can I check weather plaintext text is empty or not?

When the user inputs their weight in the plaintext area, On button click event I need to perform validation and show results on text area,

When I give some valid inputs the code works as expected

But when I don't give any input the App force stops

Here is the code

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var weight = editText.text //store input from plaintext to variable

    button.setOnClickListener  { //on click event for button..

        //textView3.text=weight

        if (  /* how to check here    */       ) // condition here
        {
            textView2.text="Give some inputs plz :-" //
        }
        else
        {
            var res = findWeight(weight.toString().toDouble())

            textView2.text= "your weight on mars is" + " " +res.toString()
        }
    }
}

fun findWeight(userWeight: Double): Double {
    return userWeight * marsGrav
}
```

Please see the kotlin code
when there is no input it should say "Please enter some input"

What can I put in the `if` condition to check if the user input is empty?

Thank You

Comment: What exact exception you are getting?

Otherwise i normally use checkNotNull(someVariable) func for null value.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (weight.toString().isNullOrEmpty()){
    // proceed
}
```